# Get contacts in Android without duplicates

Tags: android, kotlin

I've got the following code to retrieve a contact list with Name + PhoneNumber:

```
    @SuppressLint("Range")
    
    fun getNamePhoneDetails(): ArrayList<List<String>>? {
        val names = ArrayList<List<String>>()
        val cr = contentResolver
        val cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
            null, null, null)
        if (cur!!.count > 0) {
            while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                val id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NAME_RAW_CONTACT_ID))
                val name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME))
                val number = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER))
                names.add(listOf(id, name, number))
            }
        }
        return names
    }
```

The output is correct once no contact has two phone numbers. However once any contact has two phone numbers I get the contact twice. It has the same id and name, but a different phone number. How can I make it so that the returned list does not have a contact twice but all phone numbers inside a list?

Something like

`[1, Name Name, [phonenumber1, phonenumber2]],[2, Name Name, [phonenumber1]]`

Then I could just iterate through the phonenumberlist and have all numbers as valid strings.

Comment: You can write your own logic to reduce the result as you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should rather create a **POJO** Object and than assign the data into it and return a list of that POJO Object and then you can make use of **distinct** extension on the list to get a filtered result they way you want it .
This is how you can achieve what you want :

Create a POJO Object :

```
data class Contact(
val id : String ,
val name : String, 
val number : String)
```

And then when retrieveing the data you can do the following :

```
   @SuppressLint("Range")
    
    fun getNamePhoneDetails(): MutableList<Contact>? {
        val names = MutableList<Contact>()
        val cr = contentResolver
        val cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
            null, null, null)
        if (cur!!.count > 0) {
            while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                val id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NAME_RAW_CONTACT_ID))
                val name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME))
                val number = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER))
                names.add(Contact(id , name , number))
            }
        }
        return names
    }
```

And then while retreiving the data you need to just filter the list in the following manner :

```
 val list = getNamePhoneDetails()
 list.distinctBy { it.number }.forEach { println(it) }
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the quick answer. However the last line does not work for me. `list.distinctBy { it.contact }.forEach { println(it) }` gives an `Unresolved reference: contact`. As i never worked with POJO Pbjects yet, what do I need to do there?

Also you are missing a `)` in the line with names.add

Comment: My Bad . Basically just replace contact with number and you are good to go

Comment: Somehow I still don't understand the last line. Sorry for the repeated questions.
`fun getContacts(): ArrayList<Contact>? {
        val list = getNamePhoneDetails()
        list?.distinctBy { it.number }?.forEach { println(it) }

        return list
    }`

This will also just return me the element with multiple number multiple times. What's wrong with that?

Comment: I just tested, If I change `it.number` to `it.id` it works but drops the second phone number. How can I still keep the phone number?

Comment: Filter the list. If the id is same then change the id to null and then proceed